# PHP functions 101 question, really simple

Tags: php

I'm kind of slow in the head so can someone tell me why this isn't working:

```
function foo() {
    $bar = 'hello world';
    return $bar;
}

foo();

echo $bar;
```

I just want to return a value from a function and do something with it.

Comment: I don't know PHP, but have you tried `echo foo();`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `$bar` does not exist outside of that function. Its scope is gone (function returned), so it is deallocated from memory.

You want `echo foo();`. This is because `$bar` is returned.

In your example, the `$bar` at the bottom lives in the same scope as `foo()`. `$bar`'s value will be `NULL` (unless you have defined it above somewhere).

Answer (score 4):

Your `foo()` function is returning, but you're not doing anything with it. Try this:

```
function foo() {
    $bar = 'hello world';
    return $bar;
}

echo foo();
// OR....
$bar = foo();
echo $bar;
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't storing the value returned by the `foo` function
Store the return value of the function in a variable

So

`foo()` should be replaced by

```
var $t = foo();
echo $t;
```

Answer (score 0):

As the others have said, you must set a variable equal to foo() to do stuff with what foo() has returned.

i.e. `$bar = foo();`

You can do it the way you have it up there by having the variable passed by reference, like so:

```
function squareFoo(&$num) //The & before the variable name means it will be passed by reference, and is only done in the function declaration, rather than in the call.
{
    $num *= $num;
}

$bar = 2;
echo $bar; //2
squareFoo($bar);
echo $bar; //4
squareFoo($bar);
echo $bar; //16
```

Passing by reference causes the function to use the original variable rather than creating a copy of it, and anything you do to the variable in the function will be done to the original variable.

Or, with your original example:

```
function foo(&$bar) 
{
    $bar = 'hello world';
}

$bar = 2;
echo $bar; //2
foo($bar);
echo $bar; //hello world
```